# Why I have to nullify all of the session variables?

Tags: php, session, global-variables

Why I have to nullify the session variables?Is `session_destroy` not enough?

```
<?php
     session_start();
     $_SESSION = array();// <--Is necessary?
     if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]])){
        setcookie(session_name(),'',time()-42000,'/');
     }
     session_destroy();
     header('Location:Login.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a precautionary measure to nullify the values, just in case the object is not destroyed by the `session_destroy();`.

Just precautionary and good practice, it is not required.

Why are you starting a session and destroying it right away tho?

Comment: This is the logout out page.I use the `session_start` to detect the session cookie.I think is prerequisite το use it.

Comment: @giannosfor: In that case it's not necessary at all since you're relocating after `session_destory()` anyway.

Comment: In which circumstances the object might not be destroyed by the `session_destroy`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()` both.
Note that `session_destroy()` only empties out the variables when the page is reloaded or redirected to some other page. As long as it's the same page, the variables are still usable after invoking `session_destroy()`, so it is best practice to use `session_unset()` just before `session_destroy()`.